# Share Google Doc via Golang SDK

Tags: go, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am using service account JSON to create google Doc via Golang SDK but as this doc is only accessible to Service account I am not able to access it with my Personal Google Account. In the Google Doc SDK documentation I couldn't find any function to share the Doc.

This is my sample Code:

```
package googledoc

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "google.golang.org/api/docs/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"

func CreateDoc(title string) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    cred, err := GetSecrets("ap-south-1", "GOOGLE_SVC_ACC_JSON")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("unable to get the SSM %v", err)
    }

    config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(cred, docs.DocumentsScope)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := config.Client(ctx)
    srv, err := docs.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(client))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Docs client: %v", err)
    }

    docObj := docs.Document{
        Title: title,
    }

    doc, err := srv.Documents.Create(&docObj).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from document: %v", err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("The title of the doc is: %s %s\n", doc.Title, doc.DocumentId)
    return nil
}
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Digging around in the API reference for a bit, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly - I think you'll need to go through the Drive API. https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.95.0/drive/v3#Permission How exactly you would go about doing that I do not know unfortunately.

Comment: You may interested in this page https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing but it isn't strictly for the Go API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to share the created Google Document by the service account with your Google account.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for golang.

Unfortunately, Google Docs API cannot be used for sharing the Document with users. In this case, Drive API is used. When your script is modified using Drive API, how about the following modification?

#### Sample script:

Please add this script just after the line of `fmt.Printf("The title of the doc is: %s %s\n", doc.Title, doc.DocumentId)`. By this, the created Google Document is shared with the user.

```golang
driveSrv, err := drive.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(client)) // Please use your client and service for using Drive API.
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
permission := &drive.Permission{
    EmailAddress: "###", // Please set the email address you want to share.
    Role:         "writer",
    Type:         "user",
}
res, err := driveSrv.Permissions.Create(doc.DocumentId, permission).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return err
}
fmt.Println(res)
```

- When this script is added to your script, the created Document is shared with the user as the writer.

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)